# Red-Black Tree Implementation in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree, binary-search-tree

I'm wondering if there are better practices, and optimizations I could make on my code, to do things easier/faster.
I have added comments, in many places in the code, to make understanding easier.

```
import sys

class Node():
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data  # holds the key
        self.parent = None #pointer to the parent
        self.left = None # pointer to left child
        self.right = None #pointer to right child
        self.color = 1 # 1 . Red, 0 . Black


# class RedBlackTree implements the operations in Red Black Tree
class RedBlackTree():
    def __init__(self, List=None):
        self.TNULL = Node(0)
        self.TNULL.color = 0
        self.TNULL.left = None
        self.TNULL.right = None
        self.root = self.TNULL
        if List:
            for val in List:
                self.insert(val)

    def __pre_order_helper(self, node):
        if node != TNULL:
            sys.stdout.write(node.data + " ")
            self.__pre_order_helper(node.left)
            self.__pre_order_helper(node.right)

    def __in_order_helper(self, node):
        if node != TNULL:
            self.__in_order_helper(node.left)
            sys.stdout.write(node.data + " ")
            self.__in_order_helper(node.right)

    def __post_order_helper(self, node):
        if node != TNULL:
            self.__post_order_helper(node.left)
            self.__post_order_helper(node.right)
            sys.stdout.write(node.data + " ")

    def __search_tree_helper(self, node, key):
        if node == TNULL or key == node.data:
            return node

        if key < node.data:
            return self.__search_tree_helper(node.left, key)
        return self.__search_tree_helper(node.right, key)

    # fix the rb tree modified by the delete operation
    def __fix_delete(self, x):
        while x != self.root and x.color == 0:
            if x == x.parent.left:
                s = x.parent.right
                if s.color == 1:
                    # case 3.1
                    s.color = 0
                    x.parent.color = 1
                    self.left_rotate(x.parent)
                    s = x.parent.right

                if s.left.color == 0 and s.right.color == 0:
                    # case 3.2
                    s.color = 1
                    x = x.parent
                else:
                    if s.right.color == 0:
                        # case 3.3
                        s.left.color = 0
                        s.color = 1
                        self.right_rotate(s)
                        s = x.parent.right

                    # case 3.4
                    s.color = x.parent.color
                    x.parent.color = 0
                    s.right.color = 0
                    self.left_rotate(x.parent)
                    x = self.root
            else:
                s = x.parent.left
                if s.color == 1:
                    # case 3.1
                    s.color = 0
                    x.parent.color = 1
                    self.right_rotate(x.parent)
                    s = x.parent.left

                if s.left.color == 0 and s.right.color == 0:
                    # case 3.2
                    s.color = 1
                    x = x.parent
                else:
                    if s.left.color == 0:
                        # case 3.3
                        s.right.color = 0
                        s.color = 1
                        self.left_rotate(s)
                        s = x.parent.left 

                    # case 3.4
                    s.color = x.parent.color
                    x.parent.color = 0
                    s.left.color = 0
                    self.right_rotate(x.parent)
                    x = self.root
        x.color = 0

    def __rb_transplant(self, u, v):
        if u.parent == None:
            self.root = v
        elif u == u.parent.left:
            u.parent.left = v
        else:
            u.parent.right = v
        v.parent = u.parent

    def __delete_node_helper(self, node, key):
        # find the node containing key
        z = self.TNULL
        while node != self.TNULL:
            if node.data == key:
                z = node

            if node.data <= key:
                node = node.right
            else:
                node = node.left

        if z == self.TNULL:
            print("Couldn't find key in the tree")
            return

        y = z
        y_original_color = y.color
        if z.left == self.TNULL:
            x = z.right
            self.__rb_transplant(z, z.right)
        elif (z.right == self.TNULL):
            x = z.left
            self.__rb_transplant(z, z.left)
        else:
            y = self.minimum(z.right)
            y_original_color = y.color
            x = y.right
            if y.parent == z:
                x.parent = y
            else:
                self.__rb_transplant(y, y.right)
                y.right = z.right
                y.right.parent = y

            self.__rb_transplant(z, y)
            y.left = z.left
            y.left.parent = y
            y.color = z.color
        if y_original_color == 0:
            self.__fix_delete(x)
    
    # fix the red-black tree
    def  __fix_insert(self, k):
        while k.parent.color == 1: # while k's parent is red
            if k.parent == k.parent.parent.right: # if k's parent is the right child of k's grandparent, then the uncle is the left child of k's grandparent
                u = k.parent.parent.left # uncle
                if u.color == 1: # if k's parent and uncle are both red ---> recolor both uncle and the parent to black, and the grandparent to red.
                    # case 3.1
                    u.color = 0
                    k.parent.color = 0
                    k.parent.parent.color = 1
                    k = k.parent.parent
                else: # if k's parent is red, and uncle is black
                    if k == k.parent.left:
                        # case 3.2.2, if parent is the right child of grandparent and k is the left child of parent (Right-Left) ---> Perform Right Rotation on Parent, and it becomes case 3.2.1
                        k = k.parent
                        self.right_rotate(k)
                    # case 3.2.1, if parent is the right child of grandparent and k is the right child of parent {Right-Right} ---> Perform Left Rotation on grandparent, and recolor k's new parent to black, and it's sibling to red
                    k.parent.color = 0
                    k.parent.parent.color = 1
                    self.left_rotate(k.parent.parent)
            else: # if k's parent is the left child of k's grandparent, then the uncle is the right child of k's grandparent
                u = k.parent.parent.right # uncle

                if u.color == 1:
                    # mirror case 3.1
                    u.color = 0
                    k.parent.color = 0
                    k.parent.parent.color = 1
                    k = k.parent.parent 
                else:
                    if k == k.parent.right:
                        # mirror case 3.2.2
                        k = k.parent
                        self.left_rotate(k)
                    # mirror case 3.2.1
                    k.parent.color = 0
                    k.parent.parent.color = 1
                    self.right_rotate(k.parent.parent)
            if k == self.root:
                break
        self.root.color = 0

    def __print_helper(self, node, indent, last):
        # print the tree structure on the screen
        if node != self.TNULL:
            sys.stdout.write(indent)
            if last:
                sys.stdout.write("R----")
                indent += "     "
            else:
                sys.stdout.write("L----")
                indent += "|    "

            s_color = "RED" if node.color == 1 else "BLACK"
            print(str(node.data) + "(" + s_color + ")")
            self.__print_helper(node.left, indent, False)
            self.__print_helper(node.right, indent, True)
    
    # Pre-Order traversal
    # Node.Left Subtree.Right Subtree
    def preorder(self):
        self.__pre_order_helper(self.root)

    # In-Order traversal
    # left Subtree . Node . Right Subtree
    def inorder(self):
        self.__in_order_helper(self.root)

    # Post-Order traversal
    # Left Subtree . Right Subtree . Node
    def postorder(self):
        self.__post_order_helper(self.root)

    # search the tree for the key k
    # and return the corresponding node
    def searchTree(self, k):
        return self.__search_tree_helper(self.root, k)

    # find the node with the minimum key
    def minimum(self, node):
        while node.left != self.TNULL:
            node = node.left
        return node

    # find the node with the maximum key
    def maximum(self, node):
        while node.right != self.TNULL:
            node = node.right
        return node

    # find the successor of a given node
    def successor(self, x):
        # if the right subtree is not None,
        # the successor is the leftmost node in the
        # right subtree
        if x.right != self.TNULL:
            return self.minimum(x.right)

        # else it is the lowest ancestor of x whose
        # left child is also an ancestor of x.
        y = x.parent
        while y != self.TNULL and x == y.right:
            x = y
            y = y.parent
        return y

    # find the predecessor of a given node
    def predecessor(self,  x):
        # if the left subtree is not None,
        # the predecessor is the rightmost node in the 
        # left subtree
        if (x.left != self.TNULL):
            return self.maximum(x.left)

        y = x.parent
        while y != self.TNULL and x == y.left:
            x = y
            y = y.parent

        return y

    # rotate left at node x
    def left_rotate(self, x):
        y = x.right
        x.right = y.left
        if y.left != self.TNULL:
            y.left.parent = x

        y.parent = x.parent
        if x.parent == None:
            self.root = y
        elif x == x.parent.left:
            x.parent.left = y
        else:
            x.parent.right = y
        y.left = x
        x.parent = y

    # rotate right at node x
    def right_rotate(self, x):
        y = x.left
        x.left = y.right
        if y.right != self.TNULL:
            y.right.parent = x

        y.parent = x.parent
        if x.parent == None:
            self.root = y
        elif x == x.parent.right:
            x.parent.right = y
        else:
            x.parent.left = y
        y.right = x
        x.parent = y

    # insert the key to the tree in its appropriate position
    # and fix the tree
    def insert(self, key):
        # Ordinary Binary Search Insertion
        node = Node(key)
        node.parent = None
        node.data = key
        node.left = self.TNULL
        node.right = self.TNULL
        node.color = 1 # new node must be red

        y = None
        x = self.root

        while x != self.TNULL:
            y = x
            if node.data < x.data:
                x = x.left
            else:
                x = x.right

        # y is parent of x
        node.parent = y
        if y == None:
            self.root = node
        elif node.data < y.data:
            y.left = node
        else:
            y.right = node

        # if new node is a root node, simply return
        if node.parent == None:
            node.color = 0
            return

        # if the grandparent is None, simply return
        if node.parent.parent == None:
            return

        # Fix the tree
        self.__fix_insert(node)

    def get_root(self):
        return self.root

    # delete the node from the tree
    def delete_node(self, data):
        self.__delete_node_helper(self.root, data)

    # print the tree structure on the screen
    def pretty_print(self):
        self.__print_helper(self.root, "", True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bst = RedBlackTree([1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

Answer (score 3):

### Docstrings

You are using comments instead of docstrings, which is not a good tone, as I think. You can read more about docstring in [PEP 257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/). Also it's not necessary to write class name in docstring. For example, you can write `Implements the operations in Red Black Tree` instead of `class RedBlackTree implements the operations in Red Black Tree`.

### Type hinting

Your code doesn't have type hinting at all. It's not really a bad thing, but it's always better to do type hinting. You can read more about why you may want to do it in [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) and how to do it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html).

### Double underscores in method names

It's not really necessary to write `__` before the method name, because `_` is already enough. But it's a matter of preference.

### Node colors

I'd use [enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) instead of 0/1 for colors. Your code will be more understandable if you write `self.color = Color.Red` instead of `self.color = 1`.

### Node.data

Data is very wide and uninformative name. If `data` holds `key`, why don't you name it `key`?

### sys.stdout

I suppose that there's no need to overcomplicate your code by using `sys.stdout.write` instead of `print`, which also prints to stdout.

### RedBlackTree.pretty_print()

You should definitely read about [dunders](https://holycoders.com/python-dunder-special-methods/). They will allow you to integrate your class with default python methods. In this particular case dunders will allow you to use `print(some_tree)` instead of `some_tree.pretty_print()`.

### Long methods

Some of your methods are really long and difficult to read. For example, `__fix_delete`. Also comments like `# case 3.1` are uninformative. I guess you should extract each case in separate function and write a little bit more about each case in docstrings.

### Style comments

I think that every Python programmer should use [pylint](https://pylint.org/). It's a good tool to find small issues like too long lines, absence of spaces after commas, etc. It's really helpful, but try not to become pylint maniac - it's not always necessary to achieve 10/10.

Comment: Re. `_` _is a matter of preference_ - it's more than that. Single- and double-underscored methods follow well-defined conventions - single underscores are for "weakly-enforced private variables", and double underscores are for name mangling. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346